# spark streaming foreach multiple writer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I would like to have the structured streaming read from JSON file and process the data and write the data to Kafka and Parquet sinks. I see below sample code for same

```
datasetOfString.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[String] {
 def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long): Boolean = {
   // open connection
 }

 def process(record: String) = {
   // write string to connection
 }

 def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
   // close the connection
 }
})
```

But how can I pass multiple writers here? Is it like below?

```
datasetOfString.writeStream.foreach(kafkaWriter).start()
datasetOfString.writeStream.foreach(parquetWriter).start()
```

If I do like this then what would be purpose of using foreach writer? is it just for more control while writing?

Answer (score 1):

foreach() operation is an action.

> It do not return any value.
>
> It executes input function on each element of an RDD

Quoting spark [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach) of Spark Structured Streaming

Streaming queries are currently bound to a single sink, so multiplexing the
write with existing sinks via the same streaming query isn't possible.
In your current functionality implementation, you will effectively process the data twice. Personally, I will not recommend this still, you can process data per
micro batch and then use foreach or a custom sink which
writes to Kafka topics and parquet source